# Installing gst-python in macOS

Tags: python, macos, gstreamer, pygobject

I installed GStreamer 1.22.10 on macOS (Sonoma) using the [official binaries](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/#macos). I realized that gst-python is not automatically installed, so I cloned the GStreamer Gitlab repository and followed the [related instructions](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/tree/main/subprojects/gst-python) in the gst-python subproject to install it.

I'm using Python (3.12) installed via homebrew, so I gave its pygi overrides directory to meson during setup:

```
meson setup builddir -Dpygi-overrides-dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gi/overrides
```

Pygobject3 is also installed via brew in the path: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pygobject3/3.46.0_1`

Now when I do `python -c "import gi; gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0');"`,
I get an error that the namespace Gst is not available.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 126, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gst not available
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Note:** If GStreamer is installed using brew, gst-python is included but that is not my preferred approach because the brew version does not contain some of the packages I need, like webrtc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

To my understanding the [gst-python](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/tree/main/subprojects/gst-python?ref_type=heads) is only an extension to the regular GStreamer Python bindings and adds some pythonic "syntactic sugar". So it is not really a requirement to create GStreamer applications in Python.

The error `Namespace Gst not available` means that it can't find the gobject-introspection information required to dynamically create the regular Python bindings for GStreamer in the first place.

This information is usually stored in *.typelib files (e.g. `Gst-1.0.typelib`).

Those files seem to be missing when installing the latest GStreamer for MacOS using the [official binaries](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/#macos).

However when I install GStreamer through Homebrew they are installed properly:

```
$ find /opt/homebrew -name "Gst*.typelib"
/opt/homebrew/lib/girepository-1.0/GstVideo-1.0.typelib
/opt/homebrew/lib/girepository-1.0/GstRtsp-1.0.typelib
/opt/homebrew/lib/girepository-1.0/GstCodecs-1.0.typelib
/opt/homebrew/lib/girepository-1.0/GstAllocators-1.0.typelib
/opt/homebrew/lib/girepository-1.0/GstSdp-1.0.typelib
/opt/homebrew/lib/girepository-1.0/GstNet-1.0.typelib
/opt/homebrew/lib/girepository-1.0/Gst-1.0.typelib
...
```

and `python -c "import gi; gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0');"` works.

But sadly the Homebrew installation seems broken for me (MacOS 14.3.1, GStreamer 1.22.10).

Comment: I ended up editing the formulae for homebrew to add webrtc and installing from there. So it already comes with gst-python now. I didn't bother more with the official binaries. What is broken in the Homebrew installation, other than missing packages?

Comment: Glad it worked for you.
My problem with the Homebrew installation is that running a simple pipeline like `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink` just hangs and does nothing.

It was also advised by the [gstreamer-rs](https://github.com/sdroege/gstreamer-rs?tab=readme-ov-file#macos) repo to only install gstreamer using the official binaries. So I didn't look that much into the homebrew version anymore, but I might retry it now!

Comment: You can try to debug by inserting `GST_DEBUG=2` before the command, this logs all warnings and errors. Check [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html) for the other debug options.